# How to add custom properties in JSON Schema?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

**How can I add custom-properties and do operations on the json which have certain value for the custom-property ?**

Example : Defining which fields in json to be saved to a database.
Sample schema :

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
  "productId": {
   "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
   "type": "integer",
   "persist":true    // To be persisted in DB
  },
  "productCost": {
   "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
   "type": "integer",
   "persist":false    // Not to be persisted in DB
  }
 },
 "required": [ "productCost" ]
}
```

Using this schema, would like to find the fields which have "persisted":true and persist in Db accordingly.
If JSON schema is not valid approach for this, then what else is supposed to be used for such cases ?

Answer (score 0):

All unknown/custom keywords are collected as annotations by default by the implementation; you can then query the evaluation result to get the annotations by data location. You should consult the documentation for the particular JSON Schema evaluator that you are using to see how to do that.

Comment: Hi, I am not bound to particular implementation. So I am open. Do you have any recommendations for Java lib ? So far, i don't see this documented in any of the implementations.